# Why does my function in Javascript not clear the div container I want it to?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

So in this following code I tried to clear the  after
I added some Text (in this case they represent ingredients for a shopping list) to the div. Im fairly new to Javascript and dont have that much expirience yet so any help would be much appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="apple" onclick="apple()">Apple</button>
    <button id="tomato" onclick="tomato()">Tomato</button>
    <button id="eggs" onclick="eggs()">Eggs</button>
    <button id="clear" onclick="clear()">Clear</button>
    <div id="cart"></div>

    <script>

        const cart = document.getElementById('cart');

        function apple(){
            let div = document.createElement('div');
            let foodItem = document.getElementById('apple');
            div.textContent = 'Apple';
            cart.appendChild(div);
        }
        function tomato(){
            let divTwo = document.createElement('div');
            let foodItem = document.getElementById('tomato');
            divTwo.textContent = 'Tomatos';
            cart.appendChild(divTwo);
        }
        function eggs(){
            let divThree = document.createElement('div');
            let foodItem = document.getElementById('eggs');
            divThree.textContent = 'Eggs';
            cart.appendChild(divThree);
        }
        function clear(){
            document.getElementById('cart').innerHTML = '';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `clear` is shadowed by [`Document.prototype.clear`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/clear). Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. This is one of the many reasons why.

Comment: but I never used addEventListener and right now im following a project based tutorial on youtube. So I cannot implement it into my code for now. I still dont understand why my code doesnt work

Comment: Don’t follow random outdated YouTube tutorials with zero community curation. Read the official [JS docs](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference), and [JS tutorials](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide).

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked because I changed the name of the function, just like  you said. The thing with this youtube tutorial is that it's dumbed down for beginners but the more you go on into the course, the more he (the youtuber explaining it) will make you aware of those kind of things. I have learned the basics of CSS and HTML from him, where at the beginning he also used suboptimall "code"